# Read GS1 QRcode and get the data without the check digit character

Tags: java, gs1-ai-syntax, gs1-qr-code

I am trying to read a QRCode in `GS1` format. When I built the QR Code for the identifier `(01)` with the value `0100145074001`, my QRCode generator adds in the end a check digit `9`. So the result is:

```
01001450740019
```

Now, I try to parse this QRCode in my Java Program. I found this library [gs1Utils](https://github.com/tmattsson/gs1utils) and when I execute the following :

```
String brc = "0101001450740019";
ElementStrings.ParseResult result = ElementStrings.parse(brc); 
System.out.println("CONTAINED_GTIN= " + result.getString(ApplicationIdentifier.CONTAINED_GTIN));
```

I get `CONTAINED_GTIN= 01001450740019`. However, I want to read only the `0100145074001` and not the check digit.

I don't know if this certain library is not working well, or I have misunderstood how the `GS1` works. 
My question is: How can I get the value of a GS1 QRcode in `Java` without the check digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can jsut read the first characters, as the specific formatting originates from your QRCode generator.

Using `result.getString(ApplicationIdentifier.CONTAINED_GTIN).substring(0, 13);`
Should do the trick

However, the check-digit can be used for a validation check. It's worth adding a:

```
CheckDigit.validate(ApplicationIdentifier.CONTAINED_GTIN)
```

line somewhere, for avoiding input issues in future ;)

- [More info on `CheckDigit.validate`](https://github.com/tmattsson/gs1utils#check-digits)
- [GS1 spec](https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes-epcrfid-id-keys/gs1-general-specifications)

Answer (score 3):

The library I used ([gs1Utils](https://github.com/tmattsson/gs1utils)) is working fine.

The biggest misconception that I had, was that the [GS1](https://www.gs1.org/) barcode prototype adds check digits in the end, in all Application Identifiers (AI). But it doesn't!

In my case, the GTIN has AI `01` and the check digit is calculated based on this [simple algorithm](https://www.gs1.org/services/how-calculate-check-digit-manually):

[image]

So the code `0100145074001` has check digit `9` and the :

```
result.getString(ApplicationIdentifier.CONTAINED_GTIN)
```

returns `01001450740019`.

All my codes have fix length (13). So, the answer to my question is to read the first 13 characters...

```
String myCode = result.getString(ApplicationIdentifier.CONTAINED_GTIN).substring(0, 13);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.substring` method to get the required character from the given String

```
System.out.println("CONTAINED_GTIN= " + result.getString(ApplicationIdentifier.CONTAINED_GTIN).substring(0, 13));
```